# Changing texture on ActionScript 2/3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, textures

Does anybody knows if there is a simple way to change this

```
var colorTransform:NewColorTransform;
colorTransform = new NewColorTransform();
colorTransform.color = Config.ARRAY_COLOURS[1];
color.transform.colorTransform = colorTransform;
```

That is changing colors (the ARRAY_COLOURS have [ 0xFF0000, 0x0000FF, 0xFFFF00 ])

I would like to have instead of that something like ARRAY_COLOURS[ IMAGE1, IMAGE2, IMAGE3 ]

Comment: I am a bit confused about what you are trying to accomplish. Are IMAGE1-3 bitmaps?  Are they MovieClips?

Comment: Do you mean ARRAY_COLOURS = [ IMAGE1, IMAGE2, IMAGE3 ]?

Comment: @sberry2A I'm trying to use bitmaps

Comment: This code is currently working fine, but the current texture is colours (blue red and yellow) I would like instead use a bitmap for example with a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need more info in order to give you a more accurate answer.

In any case, you probably could do something like this

```
private var bitmaps:Array = [image1 , image2 , image3];
private var colours:Array = [colour1 , colour2 , colour3];
private var textureTransform:String;
private var selectedBitmap:Bitmap;

private function init():void
{
  switch ( textureTransform )
  {
    case 'bitmap':
      selectedBitmap = bitmaps[1];
      bitmapChange();
      break;

    case 'colour':
      //the example in your question
      colourTransform();
      break;
  }
}

private function bitmapChange():void
{
    this.addChild( selectedBitmap );
}
```